# How to get the comment permalink in WordPress (with HTML anchors)?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, permalinks

I currently use this snippet to retrieve a list of the latest 5 (approved) comments:

```
<h2>Latest comments</h2>
<?php $comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<ul style="font-size:5px">
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
        <li style="font-size:10px">
            <div style="float:left;margin-right:3px"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, '35' ); ?></div>
            <em style="font-size:12px"><?php echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?></em> (<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?p=<?php echo($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>/#comment-<?php echo($comment->comment_ID); ?>">link</a>)<br>
            <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 35 ); ?>...
        </li>
    <?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

It works, the problem is that this line is really dirty:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?p=<?php echo($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>/#comment-<?php echo($comment->comment_ID); ?>">link</a>
```

I use `/year/month/day/` permalink structure and with the line above I get an extra redirect from `?p=POST_ID` to that. I'm pretty sure there a better way to get comments permalink..

Can you help me? :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [get_comment_link() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_link). If you pass in the ID of the comment it will generate the http url to link to the comment.

ex:

```
get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID);
```

If $comment is a WP comment object you should be able to pass that in instead of the ID and it saves a lookup on the object.

Comment: Here is a PHP snippet example: `echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . ' <a href="' . get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID) . '">Read More</a></p>';` ... see also https://scotch.io/tutorials/retrieving-wp_comment_query-in-wordpress